# Execute a second http call only if first fails

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, reactive-programming

Trying to pipe two Angular http calls where the second is executed only if the first one fails.

First call is:

```
 return this.http.get<AssetGroupHistoryResponseModel>('./assets/data.json');
```

If data.json is not present a 404 Not Found error is raised and it should call a proper API:

```
return this.http.get<AssetGroupHistoryResponseModel>(url);
```

Don't know how to obtain this behavior with rxjs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve that with the [**`catchError`**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html) operator from RXJS.

Here, give this a try:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData()
      .subscribe(
        res => console.log(res)
      )
  }

  getData() {
    return this.http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
      .pipe(
        catchError(error => this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1'))
      );
  }
}
```

---

**PS:** Notice that the first API call will result in an error as it uses `http` while the App will run on `https`. So you'll get `user` data logged to the console instead of the `post` data.

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/make-second-api-call-when-first-fails?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Answer (score 0):

You may look into Error Handling in Angular. Using Angular's HttpClient along with `catchError` from RxJS, we can easily write a function to handle errors within each service. Simply fire second http cal when first one return error.

[Example Here](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/error-handling-with-angular-6-tips-and-best-practices192)